# Path payment accounting

Tags: horizon, payments, effects

I've noticed a [weird path payment](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/ledger/6604930) and I'm confused as to how to interpret it.

The payment is represented on stellar.expert as [GBN2KFK](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBN2KFK7FI3BXY7U3SV3JIQBAEAUXLNFKUFXKXR5HQ3DFXUU7YR6UWTZ) sending 3.333 XLM to a path and [GATEMHC](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GATEMHCCKCY67ZUCKTROYN24ZYT5GK4EQZ65JJLDHKHRUZI3EUEKMTCH) receiving 1 XLM at the end of it.

In this payment, according to [Horizon's effects API](https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/6604930/effects), the following happened on the ledger:

- [GATEMHC](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GATEMHCCKCY67ZUCKTROYN24ZYT5GK4EQZ65JJLDHKHRUZI3EUEKMTCH) was credited 1 XLM
- [GBN2KFK](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBN2KFK7FI3BXY7U3SV3JIQBAEAUXLNFKUFXKXR5HQ3DFXUU7YR6UWTZ) was debited 1 XLM
- [GBN2KFK](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBN2KFK7FI3BXY7U3SV3JIQBAEAUXLNFKUFXKXR5HQ3DFXUU7YR6UWTZ) bought 1 XRP from [GBB4JST](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBB4JST32UWKOLGYYSCEYBHBCOFL2TGBHDVOMZP462ET4ZRD4ULA7S2L) for 3.333 XLM
- [GBN2KFK](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBN2KFK7FI3BXY7U3SV3JIQBAEAUXLNFKUFXKXR5HQ3DFXUU7YR6UWTZ) sold 1 XRP to [GBB4JST](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBB4JST32UWKOLGYYSCEYBHBCOFL2TGBHDVOMZP462ET4ZRD4ULA7S2L) for 1 XLM

Does this mean that [GBB4JST](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBB4JST32UWKOLGYYSCEYBHBCOFL2TGBHDVOMZP462ET4ZRD4ULA7S2L) received 2.333 XLM? If so, why does this not appear as an effect on the ledger, is it implicit?

Or does this mean that [GBN2KFK](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBN2KFK7FI3BXY7U3SV3JIQBAEAUXLNFKUFXKXR5HQ3DFXUU7YR6UWTZ) only spent 1 XLM, and not 3.333?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Stellar Horizon bug. Looks like it is related to [#744](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/744).

In this case GBN2KFK spent 3.333 XLM and GATEMHC received only 1 XLM.

> GBN2KFK was debited 1 XLM

Should be "GBN2KFK was debited 3.333 XLM" in this case.

Comment: isn't horizon also missing "GBB4JST was credited 2.333 XLM"?

Comment: GBB4JST is an intermediate account, which only participated in trades. So the history of the GBB4JST contains only two effects: "GBB4JST sold 1 XRP for 3.333 XLM" and "GBB4JST sold 1 XLM for 1 XRP". GATEMHC received 1 XLM, everything is correct here.

Comment: But am I correct in assuming that these two effects imply that GBB4JST was credited 2.333 XLM at the end of the trade?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. GBB4JST first sold 1 XRP for 3.333 XLM to GBN2KFK, and then bought back 1 XRP for 1 XLM. Therefore, it earned 2.333 XLM on these two trades. A nice example of market-making, if you ask me. Horizon does not generate account debited/credited effects for trades as a trade effect itself fully describes ledger changes.